# error, void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c, gcc

I dont know what to do When ever I try to compile it comes up with an error "error: void value not ignored as it ought to be" i have include the libraries conio, stdlib, & stdio.h

```
void com(float n,float r)

{
    float n1=1 ,n2;
    float r1=1 , r2;
    float d1=1, d2;
    float d , a;

    for(n2=1;n2<=n;n2++)

        n1=n2*n1;

    for(r2=1;r2<=r;r2++)

        r1=r2*r1;

        d=n-r;

    for(d2=1;d2<=d;d++)

        d1=d2*d1;

    a=(n1/(r1*d1));

    printf("%f",a);    
}

int main()
{
    float b,c,e;

    printf("\t nCr finder\n");
    printf("enter n and r\n");

    scanf("%f\n",&b);
    scanf("%f\n",&c);
    e = com(b,c);

    printf("%f",e);

    getch();
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: The return type `void` for a function means that the function will not return anything. If a function doesn't return anything, hew can you use it in an expression where a value is expected to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com()` is declared to return nothing, "*i.e. `void`*" and you are assigning it's return value to a variable, may be you meant to return `a` from `com()` and declare it as

```
float com(float n, float r);
```

like this

```
float com(float n,float r)
{
    float n1 = 1,n2;
    float r1 = 1, r2;
    float d1 = 1, d2;
    float d, a;

    for (n2 = 1 ; n2 <= n ; n2++)
        n1 = n2 * n1;

    for (r2 = 1 ; r2 <= r ; r2++)
        r1 = r2 * r1;

    d = n - r;
    for (d2 = 1 ; d2 <= d ; d++)
        d1 = d2 * d1;
    a = (n1 / (r1 * d1));

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    float b, c, e;

    printf("\t nCr finder\n");
    printf("enter n and r\n");

    scanf("%f\n", &b);
    scanf("%f\n", &c);

    e = com(b,c);

    printf("%f", e);

    getch();
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Why my answer of nCr is always coming 1?

Comment: For me it seems to be working, what is your input?

Comment: I got it its working thnkx

Answer (score 2):

```
e=com(b,c);
```

but you declared your function as:

```
void com(float n,float r)
```

As your function returns nothing, you cannot assign its result.

Comment: Isnt `float n1=1 ,n2;` the same as `float n1=n2;`?

Comment: @CoolGuy What? `float n1=1 ,n2;` is the same as `float n1 = 1; float n2;`

Comment: Oops. I got confused over initialisation,assignment and the comma operator.